# Sequelize - Foreign keys are always null

Tags: javascript, sqlite, sequelize.js

## Description

I'm starting to learn how to use Sequelize and I've run into an issue with foreign key relationships for one of my tables. I have three tables: Users, Projects, Times. Users and Projects have a Many to One relationship with Times.

```
Time.belongsTo(User)
Time.belongsTo(Project)
User.hasMany(Time)
Project.hasMany(Time)
```

After I create an entry in the Times table and then fetch it the resulting record always has Nulls for the two foreign keys.

```
db.Time.findAll().then(result => {
res.status(200).send(JSON.stringify(result))
})
```

[image]

## Model

```
const {Sequelize, DataTypes} = require('sequelize');
const sequelize = new Sequelize('sqlite::memory:');

const User = sequelize.define('User', {
    email: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: false,
        unique: true
    },
    password: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: false
    }
});

const Project = sequelize.define('Project', {
    name: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: false
    }
});


const Time = sequelize.define('Time', {
    description: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: false
    },
    start: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: false
    },
    stop: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: false
    }
});

console.log('Setting up Models')

Time.belongsTo(User)
Time.belongsTo(Project)
User.hasMany(Time)
Project.hasMany(Time)

const db = {
    "sequelize": sequelize,
    "User": User,
    "Project": Project,
    "Time": Time
}

exports.User = User;
exports.Project = Project;
exports.Time = Time;
exports.db = db;
```

## Populating with Default Data

```
const {data} = require('./data')
const {db} = require('../data/models')

const dbHelper = {
    connectDB: () => {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            db.sequelize.authenticate().then(() => {
                resolve(db)
            }).catch((e) => {
                reject(e);
            })
        })
    },
    hydrateDB: (db) => {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            try {
                db.sequelize.sync().then(() => {
                    hydrateUser(db).then(() => {
                        hydrateProject(db).then(() => {
                            hydrateTime(db).then(() => {
                                resolve()
                            })
                        })
                    })
                })
            } catch (e) {
                reject(e)
            }

        })
    }
}

const hydrateUser = (db) => {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        data.user.forEach((datum) => {
            db.User.create(datum).then(() => {
                resolve()
            })
        })
    })
}

const hydrateProject = (db) => {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        data.project.forEach((datum) => {
            db.Project.create(datum).then(() => {
                resolve()
            })
        })
    })
}

const hydrateTime = (db) => {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        data.time.forEach((datum) => {
            db.Time.create({
                description: datum.description,
                start: datum.start,
                stop: datum.stop,
                userId: 1,
                projectId: 1
            }).then(() => {
                resolve()
            })
        })
    })
}

exports.dbHelper = dbHelper;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You indicated fields in camel case here:

```
userId: 1,
projectId: 1
```

And actual fields created for `Time` are in pascal case as you showed in the screenshot.
So just correct names:

```js
db.Time.create({
                description: datum.description,
                start: datum.start,
                stop: datum.stop,
                UserId: 1,
                ProjectId: 1
            }).then(() => {
                resolve()
            })
```

Comment: That worked. Frustrating thing is that I noticed that before but when I changed it I got an error. I must have lost track of what I had changed up to that point and had something else, which actually caused the error, changed as well.

Comment: A rule of thumb: don't change two things at once otherwise you can't say what thing of two caused an error or fixed an error.

Comment: Normally I stick to that rule but I guess I lost track of what was changed. Thanks for the help.